# Comparable quantification across different maps

Tags: color-ramp

I would like the color ramp / bubble size to be comparable over different maps; right now it auto selects the max value as the max in the data set. How can I set the max and min values so that I can compare across maps?

Comment: Please edit your question to include more information to help us answer your question, including data, software, etc.

Comment: Are you using ArcMap 10.0 or higher?

Comment: There is an **edit** button beneath your question to use to revise it with any additional information that gets requested via comments.  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

In ArcMap, select the Layer Properties for your raster. Under Stretch, select Minimum-Maximum. You will then be able to enter the high/low values to match for all of your rasters.

[image: Screen capture]